# Redux state coming out to be undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am having tough time figuring out why my redux state is coming out to be undefined on a later stage.

so I have an action which looks like this

```
export const coinUpdateState = (booleanValue) => {
    console.log(typeof booleanValue) //This logs Boolean 
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch({
            type: COIN_UPDATE_STATE,
            payload: booleanValue
        })
    }
}
```

and a reducer which looks like this

```
 const initialState = {
    DataFetching: true,
    DataSucess: [],
    DateError: [],
    DateError: false, 
    DataSort: true,
    DataUpdate: true
  }



export default function(state = initialState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
      case EXCHANGE_CURRENCY_FETCHING:
      return {
        DataFetching: true,
        DataSort: true
      }
      case EXCHANGE_CURRENCY_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        DataSucess: action.payload,
        DataFetching: false,
        DataSort: false
      }
      case EXCHANGE_CURRENCY_FETCH_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        DateError: action.payload,
        DataFetching: true,
        DateError: true,
        DataSort: true
        }
        case COIN_UPDATE_STATE: 
        console.log(action.payload) //This logs the boolean value I am sending
          return {
            DataUpdate: action.payload
          } 
        default:
        return state
      }
    }
```

Later I am using it like this in my app

```
render () {     

          console.log(this.props.cryptoUpdateState)
        if (this.props.cryptoUpdateState) {
            console.log("Inside if render")
            displayData = async () => {
                this.coinURL = await AsyncStorage.getItem("CryptoCurrencySelected").catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error)
                })

                 if (this.coinURL != "undefined" && this.coinURL != null) {
                     console.log("Inside Async", this.coinURL)     
                  this.props.exchangeToDisplay(this.coinURL)
                 }

                 if (this.coinURL == null || this.coinURL == "undefined") {
                    console.log("Null", this.coinURL)     
                    this.coinURL = "BTC"
                 }
            }  
            displayData()
            this.props.coinUpdateState(false)
        }
```

In the above snippet notice the initial `console.log`, it logs `true` correctly the first time, there after it logs `undefined in console` when I am actually passing false (**`this.props.coinUpdateState(false)`**).

Also Notice the logs in my code, they are logging the value I am sending correctly everywhere besides in the later stage  where it is logging undefined (in console.log).

**Question:** What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: In all your actions you should be spreading the state `...state` not just in some of them, unless you want to loose the other properties

Comment: You want to loose the other properties? I thought for boolean operations, it's okay not to spread state?

Comment: @VarunBindal please provide the `mapStateToProps` function that you use to get `cryptoUpdateState`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reducer will return a new version of the state of your app. If you don't want to lose your previous state you will need to make sure you always return it with any additions/modifications you need.

Whatever is returned from the switch case that is triggered is going to be the next version of state, which for `COIN_UPDATE_STATE` is going to just have `DataUpdate` in.

Make sure all you are doing `...state` for all your redux reducer actions in order to make sure you keep state.

e.g.

```
   case COIN_UPDATE_STATE: 
          return {
            ...state,
            DataUpdate: action.payload
          }
```

Comment: This doesn't fix it. Also I am unable to comprehend why would need to use ...state for boolean operations? Though Thanks for answering.

Comment: Do you use Redux Dev tools? you can see what actions are being called, in what order and what the resulting state changes are. This may help you understand what's going on.

Comment: I am working on react-native, I haven't setup redux store with React Native so I was trying to avoid it for this time.

Comment: Why would you not have to use ...state? The object that is returned from the switch will be the next version of state, state is never mutated,so if you don't return a new object with a copy of the previous state, the next version of state will not have it in

Comment: `EXCHANGE_CURRENCY_FETCHING` would also wipe your state, it depends on when this gets called, it might cause the value you look for to be undefined

Comment: can you please elaborate and explain your last comment

Comment: `EXCHANGE_CURRENCY_FETCHING` also doesn't return your previous state, so depending on when/how you call this (I can't see from the code you've shared), this would also cause your state to be undefined.